# When I try to change a object in a specified array index, it changes the entire array with that object. Any reasons why?

Tags: java, arrays

When I try to set a specified array with an existing object, the other indexes in the array change. When I'm in a 2D array, the entire row of what I want to change changes with the same object.

I haven't tried anything new. Just thoroughly searched for problems in my code.

UPDATE: I've even tried replacing the y with a 0 but the entire array still fills up!

```
public void addPart(Part p, int y) {
    // Adds "p" to the ArrayList of every element in components[], but I only want it in the "y" index.
    components[y].add(p);
}
```

In the Eclipse debugger, I found out that every element of the array has changed, but I expect just the desired element to be changed.

CLARIFICATION EDIT:
`components[]` is a single dimensional array.

Comment: If it's a 2D array, you'll have to provide 2 indices for a single element right? Can you show how the arraylist is initialized?

Comment: components = new ChunkComponent[16];

Comment: What kind of array is ChunkComponent?

Comment: ChunkComponent is the type of Array. There is no inheritance or interfaces whatsoever.

Comment: And what package is ChunkComponent from? Could you share link of any documentation of it?

Comment: I actually found the issue. It is because of the Arrays.fill() method. I have actually been filling an array with constructed objects with Arrays.fill(new ObjectName()) and then they sync.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is because of the Arrays.fill() method. When you change something in the array, the others change because they refer to the same object.